# Chevalley-Warning for finite rings: the degree of a non-polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields

$\def\F{\mathbb F}$
$\def\Z{\mathbb Z}$

One reason that [Chevalley-Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) is that amazingly useful is the fact that for a finite field $\F$, any function from $\F^n$ to $\F$ is a polynomial. This fails to hold in general for finite *rings*; say, it is easy to see that if $R$ is a finite (commutative) ring but not a field, then the delta-functions from $R^n$ to $R$ are not representable by polynomials. With this in mind, it would be very interesting to extend Chevalley-Warning onto the ring of all functions from $R^n$ to $R$. Confining specifically to the rings $R=\Z/m\Z$,

> Can one define the "degrees" $\deg f$ of the functions $f\colon(\Z/m\Z)^n\to\Z/m\Z$ so that for any system of functions $f_1,\dotsc,f_k$, if $n>\deg f_1+\dotsb+\deg f_k$, then the system of equations
>     $$ f_1(x)=0,\dotsc,f_k(x)=0 $$
>   cannot have a unique solution in the variable $x\in(\Z/m\Z)^n$?

The degrees $\deg f$ should not be excessively large, of course. Ideally, they should have properties like this:

- if $f$ is a polynomial, then $\deg f$ does not exceed its "polynomial degree";
- $\deg(fg)\le\deg f+\deg g$;
- $\deg(f+g)\le\max\{\deg f,\deg g\}$;
- $\deg f\le(m-1)n$ for any function $f$, and if $f$ is determined by just $s$ coordinates, then indeed $\deg f\le (m-1)s$.

Comment: Is this even true when $f$ is limited to actual polynomials?

Comment: Note also that $deg(f)<=(m-1)n$ is very weak for the application in mind because it says nothing the moment any one of the $f_i$ has degree $n$ or more (assuming you want the degree of everything to be non-negative and $n>deg(f_1)+\cdots$).

Comment: @Noam Elkies: at least, this is true if $m$ is square-free. For each prime $p\mid m$ we can then find two distinct solutions $x',x''\in\F_p^n$ and use the CRT to find $2^{\omega(m)}$ solutions in $({\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})^n$.

Comment: OK, but it's prime powers that I was most worried about.  Can you prove it for polynomials mod $p^2$?

Comment: I do not know whether this is true for $m=p^2$. Even if this is false, it is not that I wanted "everything or nothing", the problem for $m$ square-free is equally interesting.